# Error when trying to start iOS simulator: Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain Code=1

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, rubymotion

I'm trying to set up a "head-less" continuous integration server to run the tests for my RubyMotion iOS app and I consistently run into this error:

> Simulator session started with error: Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1.)

**Note that this is Error Code 1 not 4**

I clear out the simulator before trying to start the simulator, but that hasn't helped. I am not sure where this is coming from and how to debug this any further. Maybe there is some sort of log I can access from my build script to see more information?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of Error Code 4, this is Error Code 1

Answer (score 0):

**iOS Simulator** -> **Reset Contents and Settings**...

[image]

[image]

or **Quit the IOS Simulator**

Comment: Like I said, I'm doing this from the command line and I am already running a command to reset the simulator.